# Python: The length of bytearray object does not match the length of derived bytes object?

Tags: python, arrays, byte

Got some code like this:

```
some_buf = build_buffer() # returns a bytearray of ~40 bytes
align_buf(some_buf) # align it to 16 byte boundary
do_something(some_buf[16:32]) # This needs a bytes object, cannot work with bytearray
```

Alright, let me change it to this:

```
some_buf = build_buffer() # returns a bytearray of ~40 bytes
align_buf(some_buf) # align it to 16 byte boundary
bytes_buf = bytes(some_buf)[16:32]
do_something(some_buf)
```

The do_something() complains the bytes object is not 16 byte aligned. To see what's going on, I added a simple condition:

```
some_buf = build_buffer() # returns a bytearray of ~40 bytes
align_buf(some_buf) # align it to 16 byte boundary
bytes_buf = bytes(some_buf)[16:32]
if len(some_buf) != len(bytes_buf):
    msg = "Length of bytearray ({}) != Length of bytes object ({})".format(len(some_buf), len(bytes_buf))
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
do_something(some_buf)
```

And this is what I am getting:

```
RuntimeError: Length of bytearray (144) != Length of bytes object (562)
```

I am on a `Windows 10 x64` system, with Python (`CPython`) interpreter `Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`

Anyone else seen this behavior before? If so, ideas/clues of what I might be missing here?

Comment: How could `len(bytes_buf)` be anything but 16 when you just created it with `bytes(some_buf)[16:32]`?

Comment: Also, what are these `build_buffer()` and `align_buf` functions? I know of a few libraries that have functions like that, but they all return a new buffer object, which you're ignoring. Do you have a function that actually moves the `bytearray` in memory?

Comment: Not sure why the questions was down voted. The code shown is simplified abstract code. The `build_buffer()` and `align_buf()` methods belong in a class which builds some payload and aligns the resulting payload to 16 byte boundary. It basically translates to `some_buf.extend(bytearray(16 - (len(some_buf) % 16)))` code.

Comment: To be more precise, the `build_buffer()` builds a `bytearray` object from a file. The `align_buffer()` basically translates to `some_buf.extend(bytearray(16 - (len(some_buf) % 16)))` code.

Comment: You need to give us a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. It’s impossible to debug things based on code that doesn’t run and a description of what your actual code does.

Comment: I was asking if this behavior is seen/known. I understand it very well that this is not CPython bug tracker. Maybe, I was not clear enough. In either case, never mind. I found it is the behavior with this particular combination of versions and modules. It's probably a bug. I tried the same code with CPython interpreter `'3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'` and it is behaving as expected. Will probably file a bug later on https://bugs.python.org when I find a few cycles.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if this behavior is seen, and [IntelHex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/IntelHex) module is in the control flow somewhere, it might be a bug. Or at least, expect this unexpected behavior. Somewhere in the conversion between Intel hex data to binary `bytearray` and from there to a `bytes` object, a blackhole probably exists.

In such cases, its probably worth trying with other versions or on other platforms (e.g. spin up a Linux VM) for the sake of cross-verification, at least.

As mentioned in comments, this behavior was not observed with the same code paths on CPython `'3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 25 2016, 22:18:55) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'` interpreter.